# If ${f^3}\left( x \right) - 3{x^2}f\left( x \right) + {x^3} = 0$ then $\int {\frac{{f\left( x \right)}}{x}dx} $ is equal to___

Tags: calculus

If ${f^3}\left( x \right) - 3{x^2}f\left( x \right) + {x^3} = 0$ then $\int {\frac{{f\left( x \right)}}{x}dx} $ is equal to

(A) $f\left( x \right) + c$

(B) $ - f\left( x \right) + c$

(C) $2f\left( x \right) + c$

(D) $xf'\left( x \right) + c$

My approach is as follow $\frac{{{f^3}\left( x \right)}}{{{x^3}}} - \frac{{3f\left( x \right)}}{x} + `1 = 0$

$L = \frac{{f\left( x \right)}}{x} \Rightarrow {L^3} - 3L + `1 = 0$ not able to approach from here.

Comment: L is a constant, so that $f(x)=Lx$ its primitive is of the form $f'(x)x+c..$

Answer (score 3):

It is like $y^3-3x^2y+x^3=0$ which is homogeneous relationship s.t.$y=mx$, so
$\int \frac{f(x)}{x} dx= \int m dx+ C=mx+C=y+C= f(x) +C.$

Comment: Actually you cannot conclude that $f(x)/x$ is constant, unless you assume that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: And your conclusion is wrong as $m = f(x)/x$ not $m=f(x)$.